# unable to get cookies from ExecutionContext

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

I am working on getting a cookie while using `nestjs` and `graphql`. There was a problem creating logic to validate cookies by setting graphql on the module and creating `UseGuard`.

It is said that `GqlExecutionContext` can be used to import the cookie of the request, but it continues to return `null`. I can't extract cookies through `switchToHttp` either.

`app.module.ts`

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
        GraphQLModule.forRoot({
            autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
            context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
            cors: {
                credentials: true,
                origin: true,
            },
        }),
        AuthModule,
        UserModule,
        FormModule,
    ],
    providers: [DateScalar],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`guards/login.guard.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
        console.log('!LoginGuard!');
        const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
        const request = ctx.getContext();
        const token = request.cookies ? request.cookies['x-access-token'] : null;
        console.log(token); // here throws null
        /*
        Token Validate Logic Here
        */
        return true;
    }
}
```

`form/form.resolver.ts`

```
@Resolver()
export class FormResolver {
    constructor(private readonly formService: FormService) {}

    @UseGuards(LoginGuard)
    @Query(() => Form)
    async getFormById(@Args('id') id: number): Promise<Form> {
        return await this.formService.getOne(id);
    }

    @UseGuards(LoginGuard)
    @Mutation(() => Form)
    async createForm(@Args('form') form: FormInput): Promise<Form> {
        return await this.formService.create(form);
    }
}
```

I wanted to apply Guard only to a specific Resolver, so I used UseGuard instead of global middleware. Did my approach go wrong?

Comment: Are you using any middleware to parse the incoming cookie?  What about `ctx.getContext().request.cookies`?

Comment: It still throws "Cannot read property 'cookies' of undefined", and using cookie-parser in the middleware.

Comment: Apologies. `ctx.getContext().req.cookies`. You attach the `req` object to the `req` property of `context` in the `GraphQLModule`

Comment: Thx, but `ctx.getContext().req.cookies` returns `null` object. Cookies are displayed on the developer tool, but I don't know why it returns `null`.

Comment: Everything looks good to me if you are using ```ctx.getContext().req.cookies``` and cookie-parse middleware. Can I see your main.ts?

Comment: Here is my `main.ts`
-> 
`import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    app.enableCors();
    app.use(cookieParser());
    await app.listen(4000);
}
bootstrap();`

Answer (score 0):

I realized that backend had no problem. Requests were tested via GraphQL Playground, and the "request.credentials" option should have been modified.

```json
{
  "request.credentials": "same-origin",
}
```

When the option set to "omit" is modified as follows, header information is sent together.